# How to fix 'Attempt to present Razorpay.OpinionatedAlertVC' error in iOS project using Razorpay Payment Gateway in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, payment-gateway, payment, razorpay

**WARNING:** Attempt to present <Razorpay.OpinionatedAlertVC> While using 1.3.2 Razorpay iOS Standard SDK

I have integrated Accept payments using Razorpay Payment Gateway in my iOS project, I already have Checkout screen which is presented from a VC, while implementing the Razorpay Payment Gateway, I am facing issue like

Attempt to present <Razorpay.OpinionatedAlertVC: 0x7fb077a21b80> on <_60Trips.RootViewController: 0x7fb094305b30> (from <_60Trips.RootViewController: 0x7fb094305b30>) which is already presenting <UINavigationController: 0x7fb0930b0200>.

when I use this

```
    let options: [String:Any] = [
                   "amount": payableAmount ?? "10000", //This is in currency subunits. 100 = 100 paise= INR 1.
                    "currency": "INR",//We support more that 92 international currencies.
                    "description": "Pay for your Ride",
                   "image": representation?.logo as Any,
                    "name": "360 Trips",
                    "prefill": [
                        "contact": "1234567890",
                        "email": "test@gmail.com"
                    ],
                    "theme": [
                        "color": "#2C506E"
                    ]
                ]
            self.razorpay.open(options)
```

I am able to fix that issue by doing

```
            self.razorpay.open(options,displayController: self)
```

but it leads to some issues in the navigation bar,Kindly anyone help me to fix the issue related to this